# Making a KPI table in SQL or with dax?

Tags: sql-server, dax, powerbi

I am going to make a KPI table, however I've yet to decided where to make it. In essence its going to show weekly numbers derived from our customer database.

*Weeknumber

*New users (users with startdate within that week)

*Total users (users with startdate before that week, and enddate after that week/NULL)

This is going to be expanded (New users pr sales channel for example). The result is that users  should be able to compare these numbers week for week. I do not know if this is possible to make in DAX (Using dax, can I filter week by week, sales channel or other dimensional traits?) or if I should do this in sql.